# How to manage cookies with HttpClient when using a mocking HttpMessageHandler

Tags: mocking, httpcookie, dotnet-httpclient

I have a unit test that calls into a class library by passing in `HttpRequestMessage` instances and receiving `HttpResponseMessages` instances back. It's very similar to testing a WebApi `ApiController` in this respect.

The code I'm testing adds cookies to the `HttpResponseMessage`, and expects to see those cookies in subsequent incoming `HttpRequestMessage` calls, which is how a browser (or `HttpWebRequest`) would behave.

I'm not using `HttpClientHandler` because the requests aren't actually going on the network, but are handed off to the product using the mocked up `HttpMessageHandler` that I initialize the `HttpClient` with. Therefore the cookie handling in `HttpClientHandler` is inaccessible to me. It seems that to get the cookie behavior I need, I will have to manually parse the cookies in the `HttpResponseMessage` and then manually serialize them to the `HttpRequestMessage`. That completely omits the logic that CookieContainer has for correctly applying cookies to the right requests, as well.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 6):

I wrote my own `DelegatingHandler` that manages cookies for me. I also wrote a couple of extension methods on `CookieContainer` so that it can be easily used with `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpResponseMessage`:

```
internal class DangerouslySimpleCookieContainer : DelegatingHandler {
    internal DangerouslySimpleCookieContainer(CookieContainer cookieContainer = null) {
        this.Container = cookieContainer ?? new CookieContainer();
    }

    internal DangerouslySimpleCookieContainer(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler, CookieContainer cookieContainer = null)
        : base(innerHandler) {
        this.Container = cookieContainer ?? new CookieContainer();
    }

    public CookieContainer Container { get; set; }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        this.Container.ApplyCookies(request);
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        this.Container.SetCookies(response);
        return response;
    }
}

internal static class CookieContainerExtensions {
    internal static void SetCookies(this CookieContainer container, HttpResponseMessage response, Uri requestUri = null) {
        Requires.NotNull(container, "container");
        Requires.NotNull(response, "response");

        IEnumerable<string> cookieHeaders;
        if (response.Headers.TryGetValues("Set-Cookie", out cookieHeaders)) {
            foreach (string cookie in cookieHeaders) {
                container.SetCookies(requestUri ?? response.RequestMessage.RequestUri, cookie);
            }
        }
    }

    internal static void ApplyCookies(this CookieContainer container, HttpRequestMessage request) {
        Requires.NotNull(container, "container");
        Requires.NotNull(request, "request");

        string cookieHeader = container.GetCookieHeader(request.RequestUri);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieHeader)) {
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Cookie", cookieHeader);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice.  I believe over time we will want to replace a whole bunch of the functionality that is currently in HttpClientHandler and WebRequestHandler.  (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_2.0)